# Load destroy.js.erb for all users of the website

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to trigger the destroy.js.erb action for every user of the website, so that the comment that gets deleted gets removed on every users screen immediately without the need for a refresh.

comments_controller.rb

```
def destroy
 @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.js {}
 end

 @comment.destroy
end
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$('[data-id="<%= @comment.id %>"]').remove();
```

I have this working perfectly for adding new comments immediately to the website as they appear using this script, but I can't figure out how to achieve the same for deleted elements.

index.html.erb

```
<script>
$(function() {
  setTimeout(updateComments, 10000);
});

function updateComments () {
  var after = $(".comment:first-child").attr("data-time");
  $.getScript("/comments.js?after=" + after)
  setTimeout(updateComments, 10000);
}
</script>
```

index.js.erb

```
$("#comments").prepend("<%= raw escape_javascript(render :partial => 'comments') %>")
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are after is Action Cable, released in Rails 5.0

It uses the [Pub/Sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern through web sockets to send an update to any client listening. This sounds like it could work well for your problem.

Please see [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#client-side-components) for some rails documentation on Action Cable.

Depending on how new you are to coding, this may be a bit hard to follow. Feel free to look at some good tutorials [here](https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable) and [here](https://medium.com/rubyinside/action-cable-hello-world-with-rails-5-1-efc475b0208b) or google for some more.

If you were wanting to maintain the current approach with plain javascript. You could have every client send a request periodically to `comments#index` route, return html, and then just replace the block of comments with the new html returned. This would be simpler than your current solution, but more expensive on the server side.

Comment: Thank you. As I am under time constraints for a deadline and also not that experienced with coding, I think that the plain javascript approach will have to do. There is one small challenge with it: The user is able to actually edit the "comment" (just an example) using In Place Editing, meaning that if I replace the entire block of "comments", the users who are currently editing will be interrupted and have to start over. Is there any way a plain javascript approach in this case could work around that challenge?